# Como colocar os styles padrões do android ex.. edittext spinner etc

Tags: java, android, android-styles

estou precisando de uma ajuda. 
Meu aplicativo android está com problemas, todos os elementos que adiciono ele reproduz na tela de um jeito diferente.

Ex:
quando adiciono um EditText ele não fica com a borda só mostra a mesma quando ela ganha foco e assim para os demais

Tem como resolver isso se não tem como eu refazer na mão ?
Segue imagem abaixo com o problema real. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue codigos

activity_financeiro_alterar.xml

```
<Spinner
 android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SPAtlerarResultado"
    android:textColor="@color/font"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvAlterarConsultor"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAlterarConsultor"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvAlterarConsultor"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/spinner_triangulo"
    android:prompt="@string/textospiner"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    />
```

financeiro_alterar_spinner.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:text="Resultado"
    android:textColor="@color/font"
    android:id="@+id/tvAlterarResultado"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"

   />
```

.class

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SPAtlerarResultado);
sp.setPrompt("Selecione um resultado");

sp.setAdapter(new FinanceiroResultadoAdapter(FinanceiroAlterar.this, resultados));
```

Meu adapter está assim.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    FinanceiroResultado resultado = lista.get(position);
    View layout;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.financeiro_alterar_spinner, null);
    }
    else{
        layout = convertView;
    }
    TextView nome = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvAlterarResultado);
    nome.setText(resultado.getDs_resultadofinanceiro());


    return layout;
}
```

Comment: Coloca seu xml pra gente analisar

Comment: Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Conseguiu @KleberSouza ?

Answer (score 1):

Se essa imagem que você postou é referente ao seu projeto, possivelmente ele deve estar sobrepondo seu layout, você poderia criar um arquivo para definir o shape que você deseja, segue exemplo :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<!-- background do seu shape -->

<solid android:color="#00000000" >
</solid>
 <!-- cor da borda e tamanho -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" >
</stroke>

<!-- aqui voce adiciona o padding desejado -->
<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" >
</padding>

<!-- Radius -->
<corners android:radius="5dp" >
</corners>
```

Quando você for atribuir o layout para o editText ficaria algo como:

```
<RelativeLayout
        <!-- demais configs. omitidas -->
        android:background="@layout/shapelogin" >


 <EditText
          android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"

  </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Nota:** A forma do layout muda conforme o tema que você usa, logo o spinner da versão 2.3 não é o mesmo da versão 4.4 nem 5.0. Uma forma de contornar isso é criando um `style.xml` e personalizar da forma que achar melhor seu layout.

Para seu spinner você pode definir isso na hora de setar o adapter algo como :

```
adapterConexoesListView = new AdapterConexoesListView(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaConexao)
```

**EDIT:** No Construtor do seu adapter passe o novo parâmetro exemplo :

```
public AdapterConexoesListView(ConexaoSettingsSpinnerActivity context, int simpleSpinnerItem, List<Conexao> listaConexao)
```

Onde `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` será exibido da maneira abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou você pode usar `simple_spinner_item`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto você pode customizar letras, tamanho de fonte definindo como layout do seu spinner.

Comment: exatamente isso. mas como eu set esse layout spinner adaptando do meu jeito  `Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SPAtlerarResultado);
                sp.setPrompt("Selecione um resultado");
                sp.setAdapter(new FinanceiroResultadoAdapter(FinanceiroAlterar.this, resultados));`

Comment: `sp.setAdapter(new FinanceiroResultadoAdapter(FinanceiroAlterar.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, resultados));` DA ERRO

Comment: para você fazer isso no seu Adapter(construtor) você precisar passar esse argumento que vai ser recebido pode fazer assim `int simpleSpinnerItem` pois o valor que vem da classe R é um int.@KleberSouza

Comment: @KleberSouza, deu certo?